# The origin and current usage of the phrase "transition probability" in Wigner's sense

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, terminology, history, born-rule

The definition of *transition probability* by Wigner is the following

> **The square of the modulus of the unitary scalar product**
>   **$(\psi,\varphi)$ of two normalized wave functions $\psi$  and**
>   **$\varphi$ is called the transition probability from the state $\psi$ into**
>   **$\varphi$, or conversely.**

(see [On Unitary Representations of the Inhomogeneous Lorentz Group](https://books.google.hu/books?id=V2n7CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA334&lpg=PA334&dq=%22The+square+of+the+modulus+of+the+unitary+scalar+product%22&source=bl&ots=qR7V5IcE6b&sig=ACfU3U0acRpGMT1JP4eOCgO850EPbeSMpQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjW2Y6h377nAhWk-yoKHWwqCs8Q6AEwAHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22The%20square%20of%20the%20modulus%20of%20the%20unitary%20scalar%20product%22&f=false) E. Wigner
Annals of Mathematics Second Series, Vol. 40, No. 1 (Jan., 1939), pp. 149-204)

It seems to me that that "transition probability" expression nowodays is used mostly in perturbation theory, and it is a different concept. However, this expression earlier was used also by others in Wigner's sense (see e.g. [Bargmann: On Unitary Ray Representations of Continuous Groups](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969831), Annals of Mathematics
Second Series, Vol. 59, No. 1 (Jan., 1954), pp. 1-46)

I'd like to know that what is the origin of Wigner's definition (was this expression used earlier for this notion or not), and also whether does anybody use this expression nowadays in this meaning.

I've found only one new resource for this: [Schottenloher - A Mathematical Introduction to Conformal Field Theory (Springer, 2008)](https://books.google.hu/books?id=HctsCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA42&lpg=PA42&dq=%22We+then+define+the+transition+probability+as%22&source=bl&ots=Qblw17HeND&sig=ACfU3U2HHYwJ0KQ5OxfwFe0IaoT487_mag&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjYkPOB6b7nAhXSo4sKHbxzCysQ6AEwAHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22We%20then%20define%20the%20transition%20probability%20as%22&f=false). Is this only an exception?

And, if not "transition probability", then what is the current terminology for this notion?

Comment: Tip: Consider to use permalinks to avoid link rot.